# Setting public read permission when uploading file to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-cloud-storage

Searched everywhere can't seem to find a way to specify the ACL value so that the file I have just uploaded can be read publicly by anyone with the link.

This is the code that creates the Data.Object that contains the file info, there is an Acl attribute but setting Entity to "allUsers", with Role "READER", doesn't work.

```
Dim fileObj = New Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object() With { _
                 .Name = "/myfolder/2016/07/27/selfie1.jpg", _
                 .Updated = DateTime.Now, _
                 .Size = CULng(fileStream.Length) _
            }
```

Once I've uploaded I can get the link from the MediaLink property, my question is how can I specify the permission that the file I am about to upload can be read by anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Seems I was not testing the links properly, here's the code for whoever finds this question and wonders what I'm doing. This is test code, not production code.

```
Dim fileMimeType = "image/jpeg"
Dim fileStream = New FileStream("c:\selfie1.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

Dim acc As New ObjectAccessControl()
acc.Entity = "allUsers"
acc.Role = "READER"

Dim Accs As New List(Of ObjectAccessControl)
Accs.Add(acc)

Dim fileObj = New Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object() With { _
                 .Name = "/myfolder/2016/07/27/selfie1.jpg", _
                 .Updated = DateTime.Now, _
                 .Acl = Accs, _
                 .Size = CULng(fileStream.Length) _
            }

Dim mediaUpload = New ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(service, fileObj, GCSBucketName, fileStream, fileMimeType)
mediaUpload.Upload()
```

The two values for the ObjectAccessControl object are the key to getting it to work. The 'service' variable is a StorageService object that you create with your ServiceAccountCredential from your .p12 or .json file that you obtained from the cloud api console.